# How can a website have the same source code for every page?

Tags: html, frontend, dom-manipulation

How is it possible for a web application/website to have the same identical source code behind every page on the site with no change at all. I was looking at the crypto - fiat currency exchange website: (Remitano.com) and for each page on the site the code is the same. How could this be possible?

Comment: Javascript Frameworks most likely.

Comment: It appears to be a [Single Page Application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA). For more info, read the linked mdn docs.

Comment: They may be using JavaScript to dynamically insert or delete elements (either with native functions/shadow DOMs or with a framework like Angular, React, or Vue), may be using AJAX to dynamically load portions of the page with different content, or may be using a Progressive Web App approach where what you’re seeing is the installed portion. More options too; these are just topics you could start looking into if you’re curious.

Answer (score 1):

The site is most likely a [single page application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA) (SPA). This means that it dynamically adds and removes elements with JavaScript. This is why sites made with React, Vue, and Angular don't work without JavaScript enabled.

For example, if you look at the code of a Vue app, you'll see something like `<noscript><strong>We're sorry but myvueapp doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript>`. The content inside [`noscript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) only displays if the user has JS disabled in their browser.